# Subjekt-Verb-Kongruenz (Numerus)

Tags: grammatical-number, question

Ich bin beim Lesen eines Buches auf diesen Satz gestoßen:

> Etwas später fügt er hinzu: »Wir müssen uns die Frage stellen, ob unsere Technik es dem Patienten erlaubt, mitzuteilen, dass **er oder sie** nicht **kommunizieren**?«
>
> <sub>(Ogden, T. H. (2013) Analytische Träumerei und Deutung – Zur Kunst der Psychoanalyse, S. 85.)</sub>

Nach meinem Verständnis ist das Subjekt vom Verb „kommunizieren“ „er oder sie“. Und weil „er“ und „sie“ beides Singular sind, sollte das Verb dementsprechend „kommuniziert“ sein. Warum ist es nicht der Fall?

Eine Zusatzfrage: Der Satz ist eigentlich kein Fragesatz, sondern ein Aussagesatz („Wir müssen uns die Frage stellen“), und deswegen dar kein Fragezeichen am Ende des Satzes stehen, nicht wahr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Als deutscher Muttersprachler empfinde ich den zitierten Satz grammatisch als falsch und inhaltlich als unsinnig. Man kann nicht mitteilen, dass man nicht kommuniziert, da diese Mitteilung selbst Kommunikation wäre. Vom Sinngehalt her würde ich vermuten, dass vor dem Fragezeichen das Wort "will" stehen sollte.

Zur Zusatzfrage: Rein formal trifft es zu, dass der Satz insgesamt ein Aussagesatz ist und deshalb am Ende ein Punkt stehen müsste. In der Praxis ist es aber durchaus üblich, bei dieser Fügung ein Fragezeichen zu setzen und damit die Frage sozusagen tatsächlich zu stellen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe!